# How well does an Nvidia 9800 work with Unity?

Tags: unity, nvidia, 12.10

Hi I looked at upgrading to 12.10 today, and got the warning that my graphics hardware may not be fully supported.

I'm using an HP Pavilion dv5000 laptop with a Nvidia 9800 graphics card.

Has anyone upgraded despite the warning and had un-fixable problems, or does anyone have any tips for getting round this problem, perhaps using `unity 2d`, or some idea about the timescale this is likely to be fixed on.

Answer (score 1):

I received the same message trying to upgrade from 12.04 to 12.10 on a Vizio ultrabook. But running 12.10 from a dvd (which I'm doing right now) seems to work fine. Have you tried running from a dvd or usb drive? I'm assuming if 12.10 runs fine from a dvd or usb drive, it should be fine after being installed.

This is the only info I have on the graphics controller in the Vizio:

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)